# How to draw route with multiple via point on google map api android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw route on Google Map API in android studio from point A to point G, so I need to specified the B,C,D,E,and F via point between point A to G, but most of sample just explains about draw a via point, as example from point A to point C, then the via point is B. please help me.

regards

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [polylineOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline)

```
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
// add the various point with 
polylineOptions.add(latLng);
//adn add to google map using
googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

the link can help you other stuff you can do with polyline.